# Calculate the relative pulling force as function of size for neodymium magnets

Tags: magnets

I want to optimise the size and shape of a magnet for a desired pulling force. (Please forgive my limited knowledge of magnetism).

A cylindrical magnet fixed to an object will hold it in place by placing a steel plate underneath. There will be a plastic sheet separating them. The poles are the ends of the cylinder magnet, (I know that's not ideal for maximising force); the magnet will be encased by aluminium.

What I Would like:

- I will measure the holding strength of such a cylindrical magnet (known dimensions) directly on the steel plate. Given that, I hope to:
- calculate the expected holding force of a similar magnet, with the variables being the new cylindrical magnet's dimensions, and the separator's thickness.
- Accuracy is not crucial. (10-20% perhaps). Ultimately I will use that to optimise factors such as cost.

Factors that can be ignored:

- Grade of magnet. (Assume materials and magnetisation are identical).
- Thickness of steel plate: assume thick enough to simplify calculations.

I hope this is feasible!

Comment: How will you measure the pulling gorce? Will it be applied perpendicular or eccentric or even a sliding force?

Comment: @SolarMike purely vertical, i.e. perpendicular. I will increase the separating force until it parts.